# Place \ / on JQuery Datepicker based on PHP MYSQL Result

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

I have seen examples of enabling certain dates, disabling certain dates, changing background colors...etc, but I was looking for suggestions on how to place a Red / or \ on a date based on a mysql return.

I have a 2 story house I rent out. Upper and Lower Level. If Upper is rented for a specific date I am looking for a red / to be placed on the date.  If Lower Level is rented place a red \ on the date.  If both are rented on the same date the end result would be a red X on the date.

unavailableDates would be where both upper and lower are rented out
upperavailableDates would be where only upper is rented out
loweravailableDates would be where only lower is rented out

suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<input id="picker1">

var unavailableDates = ["27-11-2013", "28-11-2013", "29-11-2013"];
var upperavailableDates = ["01-12-2013", "02-12-2013", "03-12-2013"];
var loweravailableDates = ["24-12-2013", "25-12-2013", "26-12-2013"];


function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#picker1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });

});
```

Comment: in browser console/developer tools inspect the classes assigned to various date types....adjust css acordingly

Comment: You can strikethrough using css, but this will be a horizontal strike. You may have to think about a easier way to distinguish these dates, consider background images or color.

Comment: Both are good suggestions.  I will take a look at the css.